# Best way to globally use a single file across a network

Tags: web-services, wcf, iis, sql-server-2008-r2, filesystemwatcher

I am creating an app for a company. This company has one server with multiple databases. Each company location uses their own database on this single server. Neither can see the others database.

They all want a  dictionary for adding words through spellcheck. These words will be saved to a lexicon file.

I as the programmer want this lexicon file to reside on the server and then deploy a copy to the client machines on program startup. My question is what would be the best option in terms of getting the new added words back into this parent lexicon file and then subsequentially updating the client on a file changed event.

Would a webservice with a Filesystemwatcher work? Or just add the words to their database table and then parse them out to a lexicon file, then deploy it to the client machine every time and update occurs.

Comment: Do all company locations share a LAN or WAN with the central DB server?

Comment: Yes all locations are able to connect with the central server. The installation files sit on the server and they are updated and pushed to the client machine via a webservice

Comment: Question: why can't the dictionary file become a dictionary table in the database? That would be the simplest solution.

Comment: The only issue with that would be the amount of hits to the database just to add words. The users have documents of data with their own acronyms and jargon. If they would constantly hit the database then it could be a problem.

Comment: Another question: you said installation files are pushed to the client via a web service. Does this mean each client hosts a service for this? Or does each client poll a central service to get these files?

Comment: Each client polls a central service every 5 minutes looking for an update. If there is a new one found then it notifies the user that the application will shut down to download the update to their machine.

Comment: One more question, sorry: Would you be able to enable the msmq service on all the client machines?